# Why do we need to initialize a variable m, and only variable m, in order to produce a diamond quadrant?

Tags: ruby

Though I certainly admit I may be wrong, as for as I can tell, in order to produce

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

with a #times do loop, you need to initialize a variable, and only that variable, outside of the loop.

For example,

```
m=0
5.times do
  m+=1
  puts "*" * m 
end
```

produces the aforementioned image, however both

Variant 1

```
m=0
m+=1
5.times do 
  puts "*" * m
end
```

and

Variant 2

```
5.times do
  m=0
  m+=1
  puts "*" * m
end
```

produce

```
*
*
*
* 
*
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
=> 10
```

Why is this the case?

More interestingly,

Variant 3

```
6.times do 
  m=0
  puts "*" * m
  m+=1
end
```

produces a series of 6 blank lines followed by a return of 6. Clearly, the placement of both the initialization of the variable and the iterator matter (at least with #times do loops), but my question is why? If this is a case of "I know you think you want an answer but you really don't want to go down this rabbit hole" then maybe we could treat this as a fun version of reddit's "explain it to me like i'm five", stackoverflow style. For example, with Variant 3, since m is initialized to 0, I would expect a blank line on the first iteration since I am essentially telling Ruby to multiply the asterisk symbol by the value of m at that moment. However, at the end of the first iteration, I would also expect the value of m to increment by 1. It's almost as if Ruby does not get to that line because if it did then the 2nd iteration should include m with a value of 1 and hence produce a line with one asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

In variant 1, m is initialized, immediately incremented by 1, and then you begin the `do` loop. Each of the 5 times you run through the loop, m is going to be 1, since it was defined outside the loop.

In variant 2, you are closer but the `do` loop will reset m and increment by 1 each time through the loop. In both of these examples, m = 1 when you `puts "*"`

With variant 3, you are correct that the first time through the loop you will have a blank line since `m = 0`. However, since you are looping through these commands, when m increments the script will repeat, so the second time through the loop `m` is again reset to 0. You may be confusing yourself by using irb - running that same script from the terminal will yield 6 blank lines. I haven't used irb enough to know why exactly the 6 is returned, but I do know that irb will always return something, even if it's nil.

Comment: glin, I appreciate the explanation ... it helps clarify the difference between the sufficient code and the insufficient variants

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first variant won't work because you don't do anything inside the loop to increase `m`.

The second variant won't work because you keep resetting it to `0` before incrementing it.